# View-based NSOutlineView with custom selection style

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

I'm implementing a tool very similar to the built-in plist editor in Xcode. The only thing missing is the custom highlighting when a row is selected (see attached image). What's the proper way achieving this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've subclassed `NSOutlineView` + `NSTableRowView` and provided a custom implementation in `drawSelectionInRect:`.